# ASP.NET MVC Create, Edit and Delete using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For whatever reason I'm unable to Create and Edit using the ViewModel called CreateEmployeeViewModel that I created. I can however Create and Edit fine without using the CreateEmployeeViewModel but was told it was bad practive to use the main Models for CRUD. I am however able to retrieve values to my 2 DropDownList  tags fine using the CreateEmployeeViewModel, just not Create or Edit. Below are my current Models, ViewModels, Controllers and Views.

I just figure out why I cannot Create using the `public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)` Active Method.

**Employee Model: (located in Models folder)**

```
    public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int BldgId { get; set; }
    public Building Building { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeController: (located in Controllers folder)**

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private DataEntryContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(DataEntryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
    }

    // Populate Department values to DropDownList
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDeptList()
    {
        var dept = _context.Departments
            .Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.DeptId.ToString(),
                Text = s.DeptTitle
            })
            .ToList();

        return (dept);
    }

    // Populate Building values to DropDownList
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBldgList()
    {
        var bldg = _context.Buildings
            .Select(b => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = b.BldgId.ToString(),
                Text = b.BldgName
            })
            .ToList();

        return (bldg);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        CreateEmployeeViewModel model = new CreateEmployeeViewModel();

        model.DeptList = GetDeptList();
        model.BldgList = GetBldgList();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Employees.Add(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
            //return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = _context.Employees
            .Where(e => e.EmpId == id)
            .Single();

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
            //return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Employees.Update(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(employee);
    }
}
```

**CreateEmployeeViewModel: (located in ViewModels Folder)**

```
    public class CreateEmployeeViewModel
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpFirstName { get; set; }
    public string EmpLastName { get; set; }


    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DeptList { get; set; }


    public int BldgId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BldgList { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee Create View:**

```
<form asp-controller="employee" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmpFirstName" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="EmpFirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="EmpLastName" class="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="EmpLastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmpLastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DeptId" class="col-md-2 control-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">  
            <select asp-for="DeptId" asp-items="@Model.DeptList" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Department</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="DeptId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BldgId" class="col-md-2 control-label">Building Location</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="BldgId" asp-items="@Model.BldgList" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Building</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="BldgId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you please read the comments in both your previous questions! The model in your view is `CreateEmployeeViewModel` so the POST method must be `public IActionResult Create(CreateEmployeeViewModel model)` - and then you initialize a new instance of `Employee` and set its properties based on the values of the view model and the save the instance.

Comment: And in the case of editing an existing employee, You get the data model, map it to a new instance of a view model and send the view model to the view. Then in the POST method you get the data model from the database, update its properties based on the view model and save.

Answer (score 1):

In your Create method, you are sending to the view the CreateEmployeeViewModel but in your HttpPost Create method you are accepting back the Employee model instead of the CreateEmployeeViewModel. So once you change the post methods signature to accept the correct CreateEmployeeViewModel, you can simply map it back to the Employee model.

Comment: I tried to implement what you supplied above for the Create Post Controller but I get a red line on "employee" on the line _context.Employee.Add(employee); The message that I get when I hover over the red line is: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel' to 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.Models.Employee' As for my Create Get Method why do I need to add (Employee employee)? I'm only using the Create Get Method to return data to DropDownList controls

Comment: It's because you can't add an instance of CreateEmployeeViewModel to `_context.Employees.Add()` which expects an instance of Employee. Therefore, you must first create a new employee object and map each property from the viewmodel to the model. Like so, `var employee = new Employee { employee.Property1 = viewModel.Property1, employee.Property2 = viewModel.Property2 }` 
After that you can add your 'employee' model to `_context.Employees.Add(employee)`.

Comment: Correction to above. Should be `var employee = new Employee { Property1 = viewModel.Property1, Property2 = viewModel.Property2 }`

Comment: Ok, let me give that a try now. Also, should I have separate ViewModels for Create, Edit, Retrieve and Delete? Also, is it overkill to have a ViewModel for this rather than just use the main Models for CRUD?

Comment: Correct, it is unnecessary to have 4 different ViewModels for the same model for different actions. A single EmployeeViewModel is all you need.

Comment: So I have 3 models (Employee, Department and Building) do I need to add some sort of coding to retrieve the data from all those tables that I want to Update or Retrieve in the ViewModel?

Comment: You would have a viewmodel for each of the models. So EmployeeViewModel would then have DepartmentViewModel, BuildingViewModel etc. Then you can do this when you want to update department name of the employee `employeeViewModel.DepartmentViewModel.DepartmentName = "Accounting"`

Comment: What if I wanted to retrieve DeptId, DeptTitle, BldgId and BldgName from my Department and Building Tables based on the Employee ID? Would I still need 3 ViewModels or just one? If just one, how would I wire up to the other tables in the ViewModel?

Comment: Ok, I was able to get that to work. However, if I try to create a new employee using the Create(Post) Method and I dont' enter a First Name, Last Name or if I don't select a value from either of the DropDownList and hit Create I get the following error:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.Models.Employee', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel'.**

Comment: You would still need 3 view models. And that's really just a best practice. But to get DepartmentId based on a certain employee's id, you would do something like `_context.Departments.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.DepartementId == employee.Department.DepartmentId)`.

Comment: Regarding that error, you need to change the view to now accept CreateEmployeeViewModel since you're now passing it from your get Create action method. At the very top in your Index.cshtml change it to `@model DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel`

Comment: I added the `@model DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeModel` and got the following error below:


foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel' because 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpId)
            </td>
            <td>

Comment: You want to loop though a `var item in Model.DeptList` or whatever list you have on that model.

Comment: When I add DeptList after Model I get the error below:

`'SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'EmpFirstName' and no extension method 'EmpLastName accepting a first argument of type 'SelectListItem' coud not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Your DeptList is of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem> so when you create your dropdownlist you don't have to pass in a new SelectList. Instead all you do is `@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.WhateverId, Model.DeptList)`

Comment: Is that causing the error on the Index View for retrieving the data?

Comment: So, what your saying then is I don't need to call the SelectListItem here then?

`private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDeptList()
        {
            var dept = _context.Departments
                .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = s.DeptId.ToString(),
                    Text = s.DeptTitle
                })
                .ToList();

            return (dept);
        }`

Comment: You would still need to have that method if its used to populate the DeptList.

Comment: Ok, yes, the above Method populates the data to my DropDownList Control(s).

Comment: I guess my problem may have to possible do with getting the data from all 3 tables to populate on my Index Method. As of now, it's using just the main Employee Model.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample ViewModel class that would show retrieving data from multiple tables for viewing? Along with how to display those values in the Index View?

Comment: Okay it would be too long for this message, so I'm going to update my original answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks, will that also retrieve the EmpId EmpFirstName, EmpLastName from the CreateViewModel? The Index View needs to pull data from my Employees Table from either the Employee Model or CreateEmployeeViewModel along with the data from the Department and Buildings table.

Comment: To populate data into the viewmodel properties (ie. EmpFirstName etc) you would need to map from Empoyee class to the EmployeeViewModel class as I mentioned in 2nd and 3rd messages at the top of this chain of messages.

Answer (score 0):

Get Action Method:

```
public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    return View(employee);
}
```

Just change in your `Post Action Method`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(CreateEmployeeViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

var model = new Employee{
   //your logic here for example
    employeename = vm.employeename,
    employeepassword = vm.employeepassword
   } 
        _context.Employees.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

and don´t forget to cal View Model in your `.cshtml`

Comment: I tried to implement what you supplied above for the Create Post Controller but I get a red line on "employee" on the line 

`_context.Employee.Add(employee);`

**The message that I get when I hover over the red line is:**

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel' to 'DataEntryMVCEFCore.Models.Employee'

As for my Create Get Method why do I need to add (Employee employee)? I'm only using the Create Get Method to return data to DropDownList controls.

Comment: dropdown? yes youn need to bind it

Comment: I did and that's working fine. Just having issue creating (post) using ViewModel. When I add what you suggested above I get a red line on "employee" when I add CreateEmployeeViewModel employee

Comment: That´s because you can´t call same parameter in two actions, so just change "employee" variable for another thing, like "vm"

Comment: @Gerry it doesn't matter how you call the variable name. It is a problem of types. That "Add" method is expecting an Employee object, not a CreateEmployeeViewModel object. You need to create a new instance of Employee with the data entered by the user in the view model object.

Comment: Yes, it´s true @derloopkat, I modified my answer , please check it and comment : )